# WFFM where does the security risk validation message come from?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

Using WFFM 8 with Sitecore 8.0 update 5.

The following message is shown if submitting a wffm form containing < > or & characters.

```
The {0} field contains content that may present a security risk. Please enter appropriate information
```

Where is this message set?

The following keys can be seen in reflector:

```
ResourceManager.Localize("VALIDATE_INPUT_FAILED") 

ResourceManager.Localize("VALIDATE_INPUT_FAILED_MULTIPLE"));
```

...but searching the file system, core and master databases has found nothing.

I can override the message (or provide a translation for a non-english form) in the wffm UI on the submit button, 'form verification' - edit > assess security risk > error messages, but the main question is **where is the original default message actually defined?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message text is set in an `Resources.resx` which is embedded in `Sitecore.WFFM.dll`. If you decompile the dll then you can see the definition and text:

[image: Sitecore.WFFM Resources]

Comment: @PaulGeorge As an FYI, the `ResourceManager.Localize()` call wraps `Translate.Text()` so if a Dictionary Item exists for this exact phrase then it will use that. You can create this manually like Jan has suggested if you need a simple way to override the message. You can do this in Master db since Sitecore go through dictionary fallback (local domain -> master -> core)

Answer (score 0):

In the Core Database
see Item:

/sitecore/system/Dictionary/T/The  0  field contains content that may present a security risk  Please enter appropriate informatio

Inside the package it is for example in file: \files\temp\WFFM\de-DE.xml

Comment: That dictionary entry exists in Sitecore 6.x but doesn't appear to exist in SC8 or the WFFM8 installation package. I had tried searching by key and ID, and also the other typo dictionary entry (ending information vs informatio)

Comment: Did you migrate from 6.x and brought that file over ? I've just double checked a standard Sitecore 8 update 5 instance and the package file 'Web Forms for Marketers 8.0 rev. 150625' and can't find that ID.

If you edit the message set does it actually change the message seen in wffm?

Comment: It is a fresh installation found it inside the package in \files\temp\WFFM\de-DE.xml and the other languages. so I guess my ID  is unique. do you have other WFFM Dictionary's?

Comment: The WFFM 8.0 rev. 150625 package contains da-DK.xml, de-DE.xml and ja-JP.xml, but the de-DE.xml does not contain the ID you have.

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't locate that key earlier,but now i can find it:

/sitecore/system/Dictionary/T/The  0  field contains content that may present a security risk  Please enter appropriate informatio

And the plural

/sitecore/system/Dictionary/T/The  0  fields contains content that may present a security risk  Please enter appropriate informati

I think we've both realised that ID's are irrelevant and generated new when the XML is imported.